# jQuery each iteration will not assign value to element after an skip exception with different class

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops

I have a set of products (plants seeds) and I want to change their default price from 3 seeds to 1 seed.
To achieve this I have created and array with the values of 1 seed per each product and try to assign them through an each function to every product which has a class of a dropdown element.
There is one product which does not have dropdown element so I want to skip this one and leave its original product value for 3 seeds but I want the rest to change. Right now when I debug the loop it does assign correctly for products number 1 and 2 and avoids number 3 because is the one without dropdown and fails to assign third array value to the fourth product, the last one.

Here is the code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
// Create array with one seed value for each product
var oneseedprice = $('.dropdown ul.dropdown li:first-child').map((i, el) =>
el.getAttribute('data-price')).get();
console.log("oneseedprice: " + oneseedprice);

$.each($('.prices-block'), function( index, value ) {
  var divselect = $(this).prev().prev();
  console.log("divselect class: " + divselect.attr('class'));
  if (divselect.attr('class') == 'dropdown') {
      $(this).html(oneseedprice[index]);
      console.log(oneseedprice[index]);
  }
  // If element does not have dropdown select
  if (divselect.attr('class') == 'rating') {
      console.log("no dropdown");
      return true;
  }
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- PRODUCT 1 -->
<div class="ajax_block_product">
  <h1>PRODUCT 1</h1>
<div class="dropdown">
    <a href="#">
       Number of seeds: <strong>1</strong>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown">
      <li data-price="€ 8.50">
        Number of seeds: <span>1</span>
      </li>
      <li data-price="€ 21.50">
        Number of seeds: <span>3<span>
      </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="just-another-element-class"></div>
<div class="prices-block">
      <!-- Price by default -->
      <span>Price: </span><span class="price">€ 21.50</span>
</div>
</div>
<!-- PRODUCT 2 -->
<div class="ajax_block_product">
  <h1>PRODUCT 2</h1>
<div class="dropdown">
    <a href="#">
       Number of seeds: <strong>1</strong>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown">
      <li data-price="€ 7.20">
        Number of seeds: <span>1</span>
      </li>
      <li data-price="€ 18.40">
        Number of seeds: <span>3<span>
      </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="just-another-element-class"></div>
<div class="prices-block">
      <!-- Price by default -->
      <span>Price: </span><span class="price">€ 18.40</span>
</div>
</div>

<!-- PRODUCT 3  no dropdown-->
<div class="ajax_block_product">
  <h1>PRODUCT 3</h1>
<div class="rating"></div>
<div class="just-another-element-class"></div>
<div class="prices-block">
      <!-- Price by default -->
      <span>Price: </span><span class="price">€ 39.95</span>
</div>
</div>

<!-- PRODUCT 4 -->
<div class="ajax_block_product">
    <h1>PRODUCT 4</h1>
<div class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" >
       Number of seeds: <strong>1</strong>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown">
      <li data-price="€ 9.00">
        Number of seeds: <span>1</span>
      </li>
      <li data-price="€ 23.00">
        Number of seeds: <span>3<span>
      </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="just-another-element-class"></div>
<div class="prices-block">
            <!-- Price by default -->
      <span>Price: </span><span class="price">€ 23.00</span>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this: In your `each()` function, select only elements with the class `.prices-block` that are children of elements with the class `.ajax_block_product` which don't have a child element with the class `.rating`:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Create array with one seed value for each product
  var oneseedprice = $('.dropdown ul.dropdown li:first-child').map((i, el) =>
    el.getAttribute('data-price')).get();

  $.each($('.ajax_block_product:not(:has(.rating))').children('.prices-block'), function(index, value) {
    var divselect = $(this).prev().prev();
    if (divselect.attr('class') == 'dropdown') {
      $(this).html(oneseedprice[index]);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ajax_block_product">
  <h1>PRODUCT 1</h1>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <a href="#">
      Number of seeds: <strong>1</strong>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown">
      <li data-price="€ 8.50">
        Number of seeds: <span>1</span>
      </li>
      <li data-price="€ 21.50">
        Number of seeds: <span>3</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="just-another-element-class"></div>
  <div class="prices-block">
    <!-- Price by default -->
    <span>Price: </span><span class="price">€ 21.50</span>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- PRODUCT 2 -->
<div class="ajax_block_product">
  <h1>PRODUCT 2</h1>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <a href="#">
      Number of seeds: <strong>1</strong>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown">
      <li data-price="€ 7.20">
        Number of seeds: <span>1</span>
      </li>
      <li data-price="€ 18.40">
        Number of seeds: <span>3</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="just-another-element-class"></div>
  <div class="prices-block">
    <!-- Price by default -->
    <span>Price: </span><span class="price">€ 18.40</span>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- PRODUCT 3  no dropdown-->
<div class="ajax_block_product">
  <h1>PRODUCT 3</h1>
  <div class="rating"></div>
  <div class="just-another-element-class"></div>
  <div class="prices-block">
    <!-- Price by default -->
    <span>Price: </span><span class="price">€ 39.95</span>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- PRODUCT 4 -->
<div class="ajax_block_product">
  <h1>PRODUCT 4</h1>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <a href="#">
      Number of seeds: <strong>1</strong>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown">
      <li data-price="€ 9.00">
        Number of seeds: <span>1</span>
      </li>
      <li data-price="€ 23.00">
        Number of seeds: <span>3</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="just-another-element-class"></div>
  <div class="prices-block">
    <!-- Price by default -->
    <span>Price: </span><span class="price">€ 23.00</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @puzzledGalore Glad that I was able to help. If this answered your question, please check the checkmark next to this answer so your question is marked as answered/resolved.

Comment: The only issue is with the class ".price" since it is overriden by class ".prices-block". I would like to keep class ".price" as children of ".prices-block". Is this possible?. Thank you in advance. @matthias_h

Comment: Nevermind I just found the solution, instead of "$(this).html(oneseedprice[index]);" should be $(this).children('.price').html(oneseedprice[index]); Thank you anyway.